# TestNg Assert.AssertTrue Always returns False - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a util function as below:

```
public static boolean isWebElementEnabled(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isEnabled();
    } catch (Exception exx) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean chkForThisElement(WebElement myElement) {
    try {
        return myElement.isDisplayed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
    }
}
```

I call it like this in the base class:

```
public static boolean isusernameBoxEnabled = isWebElementEnabled(unameBox); 
public static boolean ispWordBoxEnabled = isWebElementEnabled(pwordBox);
public static boolean issubmitBtnEnabled = isWebElementEnabled(submitBtn);
public static boolean isctrsDrpdwnEnabled = isWebElementEnabled(multyCts);
```

When I test it in the `Test` class, it always returns `false`. I tried diff ways of testing for existence, but it only returns `false`.

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void verifyLoginpagecontrols() {
    Assert.assertTrue(isusernameBoxEnabled);
    Assert.assertTrue(ispWordBoxEnabled);
    Assert.assertTrue(issubmitBtnEnabled);
    Assert.assertTrue(isctrsDrpdwnEnabled);
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the elements themselves?  I don't see code to set `unameBox`, `pwordBox`, `submitBtn`, and `multyCts`.

Comment: Like this;

    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='username']")
    public static WebElement unameBox;

Comment: Well that means it is entering the catch block. So what is the exception it encounters?

Comment: It prints;  null

[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6dc7efb5

null

Comment: but the element exists already in the webpage

Comment: Is this a public url ? I want to take a look if your xpath is pointing to the right element.

Comment: xpath is correct, webdriver can input the values

Comment: What is the full stack trace of that exception? Not just the message and not just what TestNG reports.

Comment: The fact that you are getting a Npe, I suspect, your element has not been initialized.  You are using the @findby on a static element.  Have you initialized this page?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution that works cool with Ff and Chromre driver nevertheless fails in Htmlunit driver.

Solution for the above problem -

// Initialize the home page elements and then check for assertions;

homePagePO searchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver,
                homePagePO.class);

```
    Assert.assertTrue(chkForThisElement(searchPage.AccManagerHref));
    Assert.assertTrue(chkForThisElement(searchPage.disHref));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but I find several things wrong with your code :-

1. You have not initialized the page factory. That is the reason why you are getting the null error.
2. In your comment, you have said that you are finding elements by using `@findBy`. But why have you decalared the WebElement as static?.
3. Why have you declared `isusernameBoxEnabled` and related boolean variables as global variables. You could use the `isWebElementEnabled()` function in your assert directly.
4. Basically your `isWebElementEnabled()` is not useful at all if you are using page factory.
   Because the moment you use `unameBox`, selenium looks for the element in the webpage and if not found returns a noSuchElement Exception. So `unameBox` wont reach `isWebElementEnabled()` if it is not found in the webpage.
5. You said there is a base class and Test class. But I don't understand how your code works if there are different classes because you have not made a reference to static variable as `Assert.assertTrue(baseClass.isusernameBoxEnabled)`. So I am assuming that you have only one class and different methods.

Try the following code :-

```
public class Base {                
    @FindBy()
    WebElement unameBox;

    @FindBy()
    WebElement pwordBox;

    @FindBy()
    WebElement submitBtn;

    @FindBy()
    WebElement multyCts;
}

public class Test {
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void verifyLoginpagecontrols() {
        //initialize page factory
        Base base = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Base.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(base.unameBox.isEnabled());
        Assert.assertTrue(base.pwordBox.isEnabled());
        Assert.assertTrue(base.submitBtn.isEnabled());
        Assert.assertTrue(base.multyCts.isEnabled());
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps you.